# Global jQuery ui confirm box

Tags: jquery

Basically I  want to use `jQuery ui dialog` everywhere in same page,how could i use this?

I wrote following code and and I need to customize things that are par needed

```
 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Okay": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return true;
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

```
$('.trashImage').live('click', function (event) {

    some value= "Item0289478"

// Open DialogBox and pass some value to show user that, you are going to delete this

if it is true 
{
// go to delete

}
else
{
back.....to page
}

    });
```

How could I do that, I have many different events in same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reuse(divId)
{
  $( "#"+divId ).dialog({
}
```

whenever you need to show jQuery dialogbox then simply pass the id dynamically.

Comment: Please include some explanation of your answer in your post.